# C library to retrieve infos from ISBN

Tags: library, c

Are there any methods and/or C library to fetch informations on books such as author and Title by using its ISBN ?

Comment: Why does it need to be in C? Have a look at this website: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/ you can input an ISBN and get back links from various sources to get details about this ISBN number.